# Reading xml in java program

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read a specific IP address of a printer (the printerName) that I have in my XML file into my java program. Here's the start of the XML with the one printerName I want to grab...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Platform>
    ############################
    #Printer Specific ##########
    ############################

    <THISPrinter name="Printer" printerName="172.27.17.200" version="v2.1.113" />
```

Since I only need the printerName I thought that I don't need to make a for loop and make nodes and elements like I've found in this completely unrelated example...

```
 NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
  for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
  {
     Node node = nList.item(temp);
     if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
     {
        Element eElement = (Element) node;
        //Create new Employee Object
        employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(Integer.parseInt(eElement.getAttribute("id")));
        employee.setFirstName(eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent());
        employee.setLastName(eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent());
        employee.setLocation(eElement.getElementsByTagName("location").item(0).getTextContent());

        //Add Employee to list
        employees.add(employee);
     }
  }
```

Below is my attempt at getting the printerName... but the program doesn't do anything with it and then has problems later on. Any advice would be great!

```
    String printerName = doc.getElementsByTagName("SaberK3Printer").item(1).getTextContent();
    System.out.println(printerName);
```

Comment: You know that the comments in the # are not valid XML, right?  Is that the exact stream you're trying to parse?

Comment: A glimpse of the XML where "SaberK3Printer" is would help, too.  I don't see it anywhere in your XML example.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to get the Node printer then specify what attr and for me that was printerName! Then I set the IP address in my JTextField ...

```
  public void setIPAddress() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException{ 
    try{
    //hardcoded file path to where printer ip is located
    File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/SRC/PerfTest/BaseTest/XML/SaberPlatform.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); //suggested to do

    System.out.println("Root element : " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());//should be Platform during execution 

    Node printer = doc.getElementsByTagName("SaberK3Printer").item(0);
    NamedNodeMap attr = printer.getAttributes();
    Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("printerName");
    System.out.println(nodeAttr);
    int firstQuote = nodeAttr.toString().indexOf("\"");
    String shortenedIP = nodeAttr.toString().substring(firstQuote + 1, nodeAttr.toString().length() - 1);
    ipText.setText(shortenedIP);
    }

    catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("ip .xml file not found");
    }
    catch(ParserConfigurationException d){
    System.out.println("ParserConfigurationException thrown in setIPAddress");
    }
    catch(SAXException f){
    System.out.println("SAXException thrown in setIPAddress");
    }
}//end of setIPAddress
```